# Error Deploying on Wildfly: BeanCreationException with VaadinApplicationContextInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss

I am getting this error while trying to deploy a .war file using Java 17 and Wildfly 29.0.1.Final into Wildfly. The error message I receive is as follows:

```
17:02:24,029 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "file.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"file.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vaadinApplicationContextInitializer' defined in class path resource [com/vaadin/flow/spring/VaadinApplicationConfiguration.class]: 'java.lang.String org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(java.io.InputStream, java.nio.charset.Charset)'
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vaadinApplicationContextInitializer' defined in class path resource [com/vaadin/flow/spring/VaadinApplicationConfiguration.class]: 'java.lang.String org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(java.io.InputStream, java.nio.charset.Charset)'
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vaadinApplicationContextInitializer' defined in class path resource [com/vaadin/flow/spring/VaadinApplicationConfiguration.class]: 'java.lang.String org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(java.io.InputStream, java.nio.charset.Charset)'
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(java.io.InputStream, java.nio.charset.Charset)'"}}
17:
```

This is the profile in pom that I'm using when deploying:

```
    <profile>
            <id>prepare.wildfly</id>
            <properties>
                <DEPLOY_NAME>file</DEPLOY_NAME>
                 <MODUS>MODE</MODUS>
                 <JNDI_NAME>java:/comp/env/jdbc/datasource</JNDI_NAME>
                 <start-class>com.example.Application</start-class>
                <KEYCLOAK_URL>http://example-idp-domain.com/auth</KEYCLOAK_URL>
                <KEYCLOAK_REALM>Testing</KEYCLOAK_REALM>
                <KEYCLOAK_CLIENT>fileTest</KEYCLOAK_CLIENT>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.34</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
                    <version>9.0.30</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <finalName>${DEPLOY_NAME}</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                            <pnpmEnable>true</pnpmEnable>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

I'm still very new to these topics and would appreciate any help, I also tried to add the dependency common.io but it did not change anything.

Comment: When you see NoSuchMethodError, it usually means that you have an incompatible dependency included.  You've already identified the culprit, it's commons-io.  If you've included a version of commons-io that satisfies the signature, then it's probably the case that the server has a version of commons-io that's finding its way into your classpath, so check for that.